# Scriptaculous sortable matrix

Tags: javascript, sorting, scriptaculous

I am trying to create a sortable image matrix, 5x5 using scriptaculous javascript library by I can't make it work.

I am trying using a table but I am having trouble linking the `<td>` into the Sortable object.

Do you guys have any hint or documentation I can go through to create this ?

Thanks

Comment: I have book for Scriptaculous and prototype, if you are interested in, please contact me on PM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use floating DIVs, not tables.

1) Create a class in your stylesheet for your boxes.

```
.boxes {
  float:left;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  border:1px solid #cccccc
}
```

2) Make a container for your boxes. and put the boxes inside.

```
<div id='container' style='width:750px;height:750px;'>
<div id='box1' class='boxes'></div>
...etc
</div>
```

3) Make your Sortable

```
Sortable.create('container',{tag:'div'})
```

There is a demo of this type of thing available [here](http://github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/wikis/puzzle-demo).

Drop me a line if you need more help.

Comment: Can you provide me some example ?